# elastic query to SQL

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query is run against metricbeat. I am trying to understand what exactly the query is returning.

```
GET metricbeat-*/_search 
{ 
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "filter": [ 
        { 
          "range": { 
            "@timestamp": { 
              "gte": "now-5m" 
            } 
          } 
        }, 
        { 
          "bool": { 
            "should": [ 
              { 
                "match_phrase": { 
                  "host.name": "noether" 
                } 
              }, 
              { 
                "match_phrase": { 
                  "event.dataset": "system.cpu" 
                } 
              } 
            ] 
          } 
        } 
      ] 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Is this query equivalent to this?

> select * from table where range > now-5m and (host.name = 'noether' OR
>   event.dataset = 'system.cpu')

Comment: That's correct !

Comment: Also check out the SQL Translate API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html) if you want to go the other way around :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct besides that it is actually **where range >= now-5m** since you use the gt**e** operator in your range filter.

You could avoid using the match_phrase query by alternatively using a match query against the keyword-fields of host.name and event.dataset